# Importing data to MySQL from Excel in a PHP Website

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am building a website in which i want to give the users a choice to upload their excel file which has all the data.

Website is built on PHP, Database used- MySQL.

When a user uploads the excel sheet, all the data has to be imported into my Database. Now i want to do it programatically using PHP. Can anyone help me out with this. The code should also be able to extract data from multiple tabs in the excel file.

Thank you.

Comment: File format is in .xls?

Comment: @JensonMJohn yes exactly

Comment: what did u try so far? we are expecting your minimum effort...

Comment: i am still learning PHP basics sir, so i will try and report my progress also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with any of the below libraries if you want Excel file itself need to be imported.

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/

Note :

Importing from Excel files is harder than improting from CSV files. So I suggest you to provide an option for importing into MySQL from CSV. (Users can convert XLS to CSV using Excel)

Look at PHP function `fgetcsv` at:

http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Eg.

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, try to avoid Excel format in favor of CSV. It is much faster and simpler.

Also, you can use PHPExcel library.

Comment: the people who will be using it, just know the excel format

Comment: @NithinSas3 It takes around 5 seconds to tell them to "Save as CSV"... and it would make your life infinitely easier.

Answer (score 0):

you should use PHPExcel

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

you can use following examples

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples

you can also have a look at this link

https://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/wiki/Documentation

Comment: can we programatically perform all the operations using the code? bcoz i want the entire process to be transparent to the end user

Comment: yes you can perform all function using PHP. you will get whole Excel sheet in an array and you can perform any operation with any cell or data in that cell.